# Regarding "Let's Build A Compiler", by Jack Crenshaw

Tags: compiler-construction

<sub>(This question is mostly for people who have read the tutorial by Jack Crenshaw, but since it's a well known tutorial I think it's an appropriate question).</sub>

I'm currently reading the great series "Let's Build A Compiler', by Jack Crenshaw.

I'm learning a lot and enjoying it very much. However I ran into something in the tutorial that doesn't make sense to me.

When learning how to evaluate a boolean expression, the following 'formula' for how a boolean epxression is composed is given:

```
<b-expression> ::= <b-term> [<orop> <b-term>]*
<b-term> ::= <not-factor> [AND <not-factor>]*
<not-factor> ::= [NOT] <b-factor>
<b-factor> ::= <b-literal> | <b-variable> | <relation>
<relation> ::= | <expression> [<relop> <expression]
<expression> ::= <term> [<addop> <term>]*
<term> ::= <signed factor> [<mulop> factor]*
<signed factor>::= [<addop>] <factor>
<factor> ::= <integer> | <variable> | (<b-expression>)
```

To implement this, while parsing a boolean expression, the `boolExpression` function calls the `boolTerm` function, which calls the `notFactor` function, etc... Each function saves it's value (`1` or `0`) onto a register or stack, eventually coming back to `boolExpression`.

By the time we're back at `boolExpression`, the register `D0` holds the final value of the expression: `1` or `0`.

As far as I understand, *after* getting the result of the expression (which is stored in the register `D0`), the flags need to be set accordingly (i.e. `TST D0` - it sets the flags of the CPU to signify information about the value in `D0`).

This is so control structures such as `if` can check these flags to decide what to do - obviously after the boolean expression was evaluated.

However, for some reason the tutorial puts the `TST D0` part, at the end of the `relation` function, instead of at the end of the `boolExpression` function - which is where I'd expect it to be.

I just can't figure out why.

`boolExpression` than shows several times in the book, never with `TST D0` in the end, so I know it wasn't a typo or confusion.

I would think `TST D0` needs to appear at the end of `boolExpression`, after we've returned from all the functions and we have the boolean value of the expression in `D0`. However the author put this inside `relation`, which is a function that may or may not be called sometimes in the middle of the chain, before knowing the final value of `D0`.

Can someone explain this to me? Why should the setting of the flags, i.e. `TST D0` be inside the `relation` function? Why not in `boolExpression`?

Comment: every programmer should read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book

Comment: Every programmer can't __AFFORD__ [en.wikipedia.org/Dragon_Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book).  I'd __LOVE__ to read it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Crenshaw himself explains it here (emphasis mine):

> Now, recall that we're using a zero or a -1 in register D0 to
>   represent a Boolean value, and also that the loop constructs expect
>   the flags to be set to correspond. In implementing all this on the
>   68000, things get a a little bit tricky. Since the loop constructs
>   operate only on the flags, it would be nice (and also quite efficient)
>   just to set up those flags, and not load anything into D0 at all. This
>   would be fine for the loops and branches, but remember that the
>   relation can be used ANYWHERE a Boolean factor could be used. We may
>   be storing its result to a Boolean variable. Since we can't know at
>   this point how the result is going to be used, we must allow for BOTH
>   cases. Comparing numeric data is easy enough ... the 68000 has an
>   operation for that ... but it sets the flags, not a value. What's
>   more, the flags will always be set the same (zero if equal, etc.),
>   while we need the zero flag set differently for the each of the
>   different relops. The solution is found in the 68000 instruction Scc,
>   which sets a byte value to 0000 or FFFF (funny how that works!)
>   depending upon the result of the specified condition. If we make the
>   destination byte to be D0, we get the Boolean value needed.
>   **Unfortunately, there's one final complication: unlike almost every other instruction in the 68000 set, Scc does NOT reset the condition
>   flags to match the data being stored. So we have to do one last step,
>   which is to test D0 and set the flags to match it.** It must seem to
>   be a trip around the moon to get what we want: we first perform the
>   test, then test the flags to set data into D0, then test D0 to set the
>   flags again. It is sort of roundabout, but it's the most
>   straightforward way to get the flags right, and after all it's only a
>   couple of instructions.

(excerpt from [here](http://www.epubbud.com/read.php?g=45SM7QEG&tocp=44))

Comment: I understand we need several instructions to store the boolean value in D0 *and* set the flags correctly. But why do we set the flags in `relation`, which might not even be called during the evaluation of the boolean expression? Doesn't it make more sense to set the flags at the end of `boolExpression`, after the entire evaluation of the expression?

Comment: Actually, though I haven't checked, I think you'll find that `relation` is _always_ called for a Boolean expression.